# How to get the impala query output log into a variable using unix shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, hash, impala

I'm creating unix shell script to execute the impala query. I need to get the output log of impala query. For example I tried the below.

```
output_log = echo $(impala-shell -i $node -q "select name from impaladb.impalatbl" -o output_file)
```

Output:

```
+--------+
| name   |
+--------+
| tom    |
| mike   |
+--------+

Fetched 2 row(s) in 0.83s
```

Here I'm getting the two name output in both output_file and output_log. But I need the "Fetched 2 row(s) in 0.83s" log in output_log variable. How can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.
The way it works is that impala sends the query output in a different stream and the other information w.r.t the query in a different stream.

hence all you have to do is

```
impala-shell -i $node -q "select name from impaladb.impalatbl" 2>output_file
```

the **2>** will send the output containing the "**Fetched 1 row in 10seconds**" in the output file. Now you can grep it or do whatever you want .

Suppose you want to store the same output in **output_log** variable , then use

```
 output_log=$(impala-shell -i $node -q "select name from impaladb.impalatbl" 2>&1)
```

here **2>&1** will send the output to stdout which will be used for assinging the value to variable.

For more information on this , just put **2>&1** in google search and learn more about it.

Hope it helps you!!

**Some additional  observations**

2>&1 redirect output from stderr to stdout but stdout also gets the query output, so when you store it in a variable , it will get query output as well as the extra information like"fetched 1 row in 3seconds"

but

when we use

2>a.txt then only the stderr output is getting redirected. so a.txt will contain only information like "starting impala.....fetched 1 row in 2 seconds" . and then you can grep from file and put that in a variable.

just wanted to highlight this slight difference I observed between storing in a file and storing in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with impala, so I'm not confident that what you are doing is the most efficient way to query impala. However, you're trying to focus in on a specific line of output; that I can answer.

There are many ways to do this. Maybe the most straightforward is grep:

```
output_log = echo `impala-shell -i $node -q "select name from impaladb.impalatbl" -o output_file | grep Fetch`
```

Comment: I tried. It is empty. since the query is returning only the table output as below. 
+--------+
| name   |
+--------+
| tom    |
| mike   |
+--------+

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Solution 1:

```
output_log=$(nohup impala-shell -k --ssl -i $node --verbose --delimited --query="select count(*) as cnt from impaladb.impalatbl" 2>/dev/null)
echo $output_log
```

Solution 2:

```
output_log=$(echo `impala-shell -k --ssl -i $node --verbose --delimited --query="select count(*) as cnt from impaladb.impalatbl" -o output_file | head output_file`)
echo $output_log
```