# How to get the count of impala table records into a variable in shell script

Tags: linux, impala

I am trying to run below impala  query to get the table count from shell scripting.

```
Select count(*) as count from impala table name.
```

### Count

1000

I need to capture 1000 into shell variable to be used in some calculation. Can some one help how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959947/how-to-get-the-impala-query-output-log-into-a-variable-using-unix-shell-script

Comment: I have modified my question..pl check and help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
x="$(impala-shell -q 'select count(*) from table_name' -B)"
echo "$x"
```